# Error when creating link between java and mysql

Tags: java, mysql

I created the connection between java and mysql as follows:

```
package conexao;

import java.sql.Connection; 

import java.sql.DriverManager; 
 
import java.sql.SQLException; 

public class ConnectionFactory {
     public Connection getConnection() {
         try {
            return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/projetojava","xxxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxx");
         }         
         catch(SQLException excecao) {
            throw new RuntimeException(excecao);
         }
     }
}
```

to test the connection I used this code:

```
package conexao;
import java.sql.Connection; 
import java.sql.SQLException; 

public class TestaConexao {     
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
         Connection connection = new ConnectionFactory().getConnection();
         System.out.println("Conexão aberta!");
         connection.close();
     }
}
```

But I always get this error:

> In-place deployment at \192.168.1.70\Server\html\Pouco Comum\build\web GlassFish Server 4.1.1, deploy, null, false
> \\192.168.1.70\Server\html\Pouco Comum\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1048: The module has not been deployed.
> See the server log for details. BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

How can I solve?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL port seems to be missing in JDBC connection URL. The default port is 3306.
Try below code:

```java
return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/projetojava","xxxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxx");
```

Comment: Continues to return the same error after adding the port